# User Input function, if/else if parameter not followed

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input

I have the following code that requires the user to input a date in format 2021/12/31. It then calculates the difference between date entered and today.

```
date = input('Enter your date: ')
delta = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d') - datetime.now()
print("difference is {} days".format(delta.days))
```

I would like for a 0 to be displayed if the wrong date format is entered but can't quite figure it out, I assume I need if / else like my attempt below but it's not quite working as it returns 0 no matter what.

```
date = input('Enter your date: ')
if date == '%Y/%m/%d':
    delta = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d') - datetime.now()
    print("difference is {} days".format(delta.days))
else:
    print('0')
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime): "ValueError is raised if the date_string and format can’t be parsed". So you could use `try/except`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime to check if  the format is right like:

```
try:
....datetime.datetime.strptime("99/99/99","%m/%d/%y")
except ValueError as err:
....print(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the date format like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
date = str(input('Enter your date: '))
print(date)
format = "%Y-%m-%d"
try:
    delta = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(date, format)
    print("difference is {} days".format(delta.days))
except ValueError as err:
    print(err)
```